# Should observant Jews travel to areas that are centres for Avodah Zarah (Idol worship)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, avodah-zarah, travel

In the light of the recent tragic event in Nepal, the question arose in my mind whether observant Jews ought specifically to travel to the far east where avodah zarah is intrinsic to the society?

Comment: In the US Christmas is a government sanctioned holiday!

Comment: for what purpose? if one has no choice then it's ok like the biblical patriarchs who went to egypt for food.

Comment: @ray - The purpose is just to travel, see the sights (can add to admire the beautiful creation of Hashem that is nature) - I don't refere to outreach/kiruv such as Habad.

Comment: are you asking from halacha or hashkafa

Comment: Hashkafah. Halacha gets more complicated.

Comment: Are you asking whether we *should* (whether there's a specific reason to do so) or whether we may (whether there's a specific reason not to)?

Comment: Both questions are valid, but I was aiming more at should.

Comment: @Epicentre I'm not following what this has to do with recent events.  What about the recent tragedy would say we should all go to areas of avoda zarah? Also, do you mean we should go _even though_ they are centers of avodah zarah? (i.e. your question seems to ask if we _should_ go and only provide rationale why we _shouldn't_)

Comment: Personally I feel that these areas are unsuitable for observant Jews.  Of course there is free will but I was interested to raise the subject for discussion.

Comment: @Epicentre, based on that last comment I have to vote to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: OK if you feel that way. Nevertheless it's an item very relevant at he moment.

Comment: @Epicentre I'm still unclear.  Are you sure you don't mean to ask if we _may_ go?  You've offered reasons why we _shouldn't_ and want to know if we specifically _should_?

Comment: The question was edited. Maybe it would be better unedited.

Comment: @Epicentre There is a Chabad in Kathmandu http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/118561/jewish/Chabad-House-of-Kathmandu.htm. So, there is at least one example of an Orthdox organization not only visiting Nepal, but actually living there. Whether or not you should enter any of the temples or monasteries might be a different question. I imagine if you are visiting Nepal as a tourist, the avodah zorah cultural centers would be the primary reason to visit.

Comment: Of course Chabad are there, but 1) they are specifically there to bring forces of kedushah and provide some Yiddishkeit to the tourists to prevent them hv"h turning aside 2) they are sufficiently committed in their beliefs to be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Shaarei Kedusha Part 4 Gate 3

> And all the time that the soul of man clings to him, may He be blessed
>   in this way, no bad thing will happen to him, and he will not ever
>   come to error in any matter of his matters, whether in intellectual or
>   emotional, and he will not fall in the hand of chance (the natural
>   order) because as he's clinging with G-d, he is above all happenings,
>   and rules over them. And in honor of H' may He be blessed, he should
>   be careful not to cling his thoughts in Him except in clean places,
>   and not in dirty alleyways, and not with unclean hands, and not in
>   front of idols, or the like. And I heard from a wise G-d fearing man,
>   that he saw the pious Rebi Yitchak the son of the Ravad z''l who he
>   served, and he said that the pious man (R.Yitzchak) all of his days,
>   his physical eyes did not see anything because he was blind, and when
>   he needed to go to some place, he would say to his student who went
>   with him that when he reaches a place of idol worship, hurry your
>   footsteps as much as possible. And it appears to me that all of this
>   he did in honor of H-shem, may He be blessed, because he needed to not
>   think while in a place of ultimate tuma (impurity) thoughts of Him
>   which is the ultimate kedusha (holiness). And he would hurry to
>   passover in order to return to the point where he left off.

so it seems better to avoid such places if possible.